# Why doesn't smart-cast handle this situation?

Tags: kotlin

I have some code with a similar structure to this:

```
private fun test() : Double {
    val a : Double? = 15.0
    val b : Double? = 20.0
    return if (a == null && b == null) {
        0
    } else if (a != null && b == null) {
        a
    } else if (a == null && b != null) {
        b
    } else {
        a+b
    }
}
```

From my understanding, smart casting should infer that in the final 'else' statement, neither a nor b can be null, yet it doesn't seem to infer this which results in an error.

Is there a legitimate reason that smartcasting isn't working in the way I expect here, or is it just not as smart as I think it is?

Comment: Please report this as a bug to the Kotlin issue tracker if you do not find an existing bug that matches.  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com  ... you can then note the bug you created here so others can find it.  Your bug report can be added as an answer to your own question or you can update the question to note the link to the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just isn't as smart as you think it is.

There are a slew of smart cast related issues in IntelliJ IDEA's issue tracking system. e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6822 which is a subtask of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-2454 which lists other possibly related issues. I would go through those and see if your issue is already tracked or not and, if not, creating one for this and see what comes of it.