# Is it possible to return the same type as the type parameter in when statement

Tags: generics, types, kotlin

For example:

```
fun <T> f(a: T): T =
    when (a) {
        a is Int -> 0  // if T is Int, then return Int
        a is String -> ""  // if T is String, then return String
        else -> throw RuntimeException()  // Otherwise, throw an exception so that the return type does not matter.
    }
```

It gives compile errors:

```
Error:(3, 20) The integer literal does not conform to the expected type T
Error:(4, 23) Type mismatch: inferred type is String but T was expected
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast the result to `T` afterwards. You won't get any compiler assistance with that and you will get warnings, but at least it does compile:

```
fun <T> f(a: T): T =
    when {
        a is Int -> 0  // if T is Int, then return Int
        a is String -> ""  // if T is String, then return String
        else -> throw RuntimeException()  // Otherwise, throw an exception so that the return type does not matter.
    } as T
```

Note that `when (a)` here is unnecessary, just `when {` is enough.

Comment: You could also write `when(a)`, and just write `is Int ->` in each of the cases. You won't repeat `a` for every case this way.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, when the Kotlin compiler analyzes a function, it does not assume certain particular cases of a type parameter for the parts of the body.

Instead, the code that works with a type parameter `T` is supposed to be correct with any `T`. Returning an `Int` where `T` is expected is not considered safe just because it's not analyzed deep enough to proof that `T` is always a supertype of `Int` if the function reaches that branch.

One option is just to make an unchecked cast to `T`, as in @nhaarman's answer, thus expressing that you are sure that the types are correct.

Another solution is to make several overloads of your function that work with different types:

```
fun f(a: Int) = 1
fun f(a: String) = ""
fun f(a: Any): Nothing = throw RuntimeException()
```

In this case, the compiler will choose the function overload based on the argument you pass, in contrast with specializing a single generic function to a certain type argument, and this is a simpler task for the compiler, because it does not involve any type analysis inside a function body.

---

Also, similar question:

- [Kotlin reified type parameter doesn't smart cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858672/kotlin-reified-type-parameter-doesnt-smart-cast)
- [Why doesn't smart-cast handle this situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010442/why-doesnt-smart-cast-handle-this-situation)